Как очистить консоль в питон?
Я хочу сделать анимацию загрузки меню, он добавляет до трёх точек после "Loading" и потом должен начать заново, но потом он пишет сверху него (кажется), в интернете не нашёл ответа. Вот мой код:
import time
while True:
     print('Loading', end = "\r")
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print('Loading.', end = "\r")
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print('Loading..', end = "\r")
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print('Loading...', end = "'\r")
     time.sleep(0.5)


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Главная идея – затирать строку пробелами, если вы собираетесь печатать меньше символов чем было. Ещё я перегруппировал печать так, чтобы курсор был виден в конце строки. Остальные изменения – косметика:
import time

while True:
     print('\r          ', end='')
     print('\rLoading'   , end='', flush=True)
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print('\rLoading.'  , end='', flush=True)
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print('\rLoading..' , end='', flush=True)
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print('\rLoading...', end='', flush=True)
     time.sleep(0.5)

Ещё можно уменьшить обновление экрана:
import time

print('Loading', end='', flush=True)
while True:
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print('.', end='', flush=True)
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print('.', end='', flush=True)
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print('.', end='', flush=True)
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print('\b \b\b \b\b \b', end='', flush=True)


Это всё чтоб почистить эту несчастную консоль?!

@FoxFox, да, это чтобы создать анимацию в одной строке без использования тяжёлых библиотек вроде ncurses.

Консоль - отстой позавчерашнего дня. На что люди время тратят, не перестаю удивляться.

@FoxFox, консоль - отличный инструмент, которым я пользуюсь каждый день. И для которого каждый день пишу инструменты.

Вам я напишу ответ, хотя сейчас понабегают и начнут рассказывать о "мусоре в комментах". Знаете как будет называться профессия "программист" через 5-10 лет? Постановщик задач для ИИ в части управления языковыми модулями. Какие ещё консоли допотопные? Чему учат этих людей сейчас в школах и вузах? Зачем? Windows ближайшего будущего - это не примитивные консоли и даже не мышка с клавиатурой. Это голосовое управление интрасетью или облаками. Все эти писатели переключения раскладок клавиатуры - будущие безработные. Не верится? Будем подождать чутка.

Очистить консоль можно при помощи встроенной библиотеки os.
Для Windows используется команда cls, а для unix/linux и macOS - clear
import os

def clear_my_console():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


Можно добавить ещё один цикл, приправить f-строками, тем самым сократив код. К тому же курсор не будет прыгать, но останется видимым - как бы создавая границы загрузки.
import time

while True:
    for i in range(4):  
        print(f"\rLoading{'.'*i}{' '*(3-i)}", end='')  
        time.sleep(0.5)



Спасибо большое, теперь я могу доделать свою программу
